# Strange error in logs: send_done_cb: No such interface 'org.gtk.vfs.Enumerator' on object at path etc

Tags: linux-mint, d-bus

I recently installed Linux Mint 18.1. My system seems to be working fine, but for the last several hours I've been seeing `/var/log/syslog` lines such as the following:

```
Dec 30 16:18:04 myhost dbus[848]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service'
```

I found some forum post suggesting I see what `systemctl status shadow.service` tells me. Well, here it is:

```
# systemctl status shadow.service
● shadow.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

but it doesn't say exactly what's missing.

Why is this happening? What can I do about it?